# Ubuntu is not listed in boot menu after Wubi installation Win 7

Tags: installation

I have installed Ubuntu using wubi in Win 7. When I restart my computer it is not showing the list of ubuntu in the list of operating system. I have checked in My Computer->Properties->Advanced->Under Startup and recovery Settings->time to display operating systems is 10 seconds. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you used Wubi, Ubuntu will appear in the Windows boot menu. Press F8 when booting Windows and you should see a menu similar to the image below:

[image]

Select Ubuntu and you are done. Very different from actually installing Ubuntu from the LiveCD where you would have the system completely separate from Windows. For example if something happens to the Windows system like a virus, corruption, boot error, etc.. any problem that eliminates the possibility to boot windows then you will be left temporally without Linux or Windows.

In the case of the LiveCD installation like the image below:

[image]

It is less prone to virus/corruption problems.

Comment: Thank you for your reply butwhen pressing F8 it does not show the option to choose ubuntu. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Ok you got me there. If it does not appear when you press F8 then there is a serious problem but with windows. I can not guess right now but I would recommend running any partition program or a LiveCD of Ubuntu to see if there is a partition with Ubuntu in it. If you installed ubuntu with Wubi and selected to install it in the same partition as Windows it should appear in the Boot mennu for it (F8 Key). If not it should appear when booting the PC (Press ESC or leave SHIFT pressed while booting). If you could check this it would help.

Comment: THanks for your prompt reply. When I press ESC it shows only Windows 7 as the operating system. And when I press Shift nothing happens. Sorry I am new to this operating system installation, so do I need to partition my drive?

Comment: I recommend installing Ubuntu from the LiveCD. Not inside Windows. It will save you time, problems and if you already have Ubuntu installed but lost in some mystical partition, the LiveCD installer will tell you and solve it for you. Go with the Force Luke, use the LiveCD.

Comment: Thanks! Correct me if I am wrong, I should have LiveCD in the CD that has wubi? When I try to boot with the CD that has wubi it does not show up.

Comment: Yes Gaurab. The same CD that has Wubi is the LiveCD. If it appears as a black screen just press ESC. The LiveCD menu should appear. If you do not press anything and just boot from the LiveCD then wait a couple of minutes. It should load a screen where it asks you to install or test drive Ubuntu. If any case nothing of this happens burn the image again or download it again. Just in case.

Comment: ok thanks a lot! I will burn the CD again cause it is going to Windows directly not booting form CD.